# Profile2, url rewrite

Tags: 7, path-aliases, users, uri

How do I create a path like this `www.example.com/PROFILE_NAME/FULL_NAME`

FULL_NAME is a [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) field.

With pathauto you cannot modify profile2 entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ["quick dirty workaround"](http://drupal.org/node/1330546#comment-5203836) to making profile2 entities work with tokens/pathauto properly if you're interested.

It doesn't work for bulk generation, but does for individual saves of an entity.

It seems there is an ongoing effort to get this solved (http://drupal.org/node/1330546), but nothing's been added in a couple of months. It might be worth checking the issue queue/recent release notes to see if you can find out where they are with this.

Comment: How can I get this code? http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1332096.git gives me a 404 page...

Comment: You can't visit a git URL using HTTP, You'll need to use git to clone the repository. The instructions are on the [sandbox page](http://drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1332096), but the command is: `git clone http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1332096.git pathauto_integration_for_all_entity_types`. I've just cloned it and the expected files are there.

Comment: Thanks Clive, it was the first time I'm using git and sandbox in this way. I've downloaded the folder now I've got two files .info .module and one folder .git. Should I copy the two files into a new folder and add it in my modules folder? Anyway, is this module stable? Thanks Clive

Comment: Thanks Clive, it works as expected. i cannot update the existing but if I change name of the profile or of the field It's changing automatically the url as well. I will follow the issue to see if there is any news.