# What are the replacement patterns or tokens for Profile2 URL of a particular user?

Tags: tokens, users

I just need to know how to key in token replacements for any given users different profiles. In my projects a user can have multiple profiles associated with the account. I am just having problems with tokens on how to locate or recreate those urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

1. First Install **Pathauto Module**.
2. Login in drupal as administrator, and goto **Configuration.** Under **'SEARCH AND METADATA'** select **'URL aliases'**.
3. Select **'Pattern'** tab and goto **'USER PATHS'** and click on **'REPLACEMENT PATTERNS'** a list will appear.
4. Select **'Users'** and again some more option will be displayed, select 'name' and the '**pattern for user account page paths** should be displayed as **'[user:name]'** and save it.
5. In the same window **'Bulk update'** tab and check mark the **User Paths** and click **Update**.

The following output will be http://example.com/username.

Comment: The thing is there are more than one profile and I need replacement patterns for either profile based on either the name of the user name or the secondary profile name that is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since it's still unanswered...

This is still a lingering issue in the Profile2 issue queue. As yet, there's no official module that lets you use tokens with Profile2. mohit_rocks answer really only applies to the core profile module AFAIK.

To get custom URLs without token, you can simple create a profile, export it, edit the URL in the export, and then import it.

Details here: https://drupal.org/node/1054740 (response #1)
And here: https://drupal.org/node/1149636#comment-5320062

That second thread mentions a sandbox project that " is a quick-and-dirty integration between Pathauto and all the entity types that have an Entity URI." See https://drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1332096

And having written all that up, I just saw there's a similar answer here: [Profile2, url rewrite](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39289/profile2-url-rewrite)